# Ranking each group of table rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with this structure :

```
ID   NAME   RANK
10    A      1
11    A      2
12    A      3
13    A      4
14    B      1
15    B      2
```

This table is huge and around 500 rows are inserted to it every minute. To maintain ordering for each group, by name, we are using a before insert trigger like the following:

```
begin

    SELECT NVL(MAX(RANK+1),1) INTO RANK FROM tablename
    WHERE NAME=:NEW.NAME;

end;
```

This works well but sometimes it returns incorrect values e.g (14,8,11,4,5) instead of (1,2,3,4,5). We investigated our code so we didn't update this column.

What could be the problem? If this method for ranking is wrong, what is the best method to do that?

Comment: To get higher values than expected is strange. If it had been lower values, I would have said, it's because of parallel writes, so that several inserts detect the same max value. Sorry, I have no idea what's wrong. However, do you really need the ranks with increments of one? Usually you would just use a sequence, thus getting A/1, A/2, B/3, A/4 for instance. The ranks for A would be 1,2,4, which is not increments of one, but still ordered. Wouldn't that suffice?

Comment: We can't use this method for ranking because we are using this column in other calculation and it should be ordered for each group.

Comment: Is the (select max) when we have too many parallel insert return wrong results?

Comment: When having two parellel inserts on A, they both would ask for the max value, which is 4 at that time, and they would both insert A/5.

Comment: I don't understand why the suggested sequence method cannot be useed for ranking. It _is_ ordered for each group. Only there are gaps, but who cares? If you really need increments of 1 than use an aggregate function on your rank column. (You shouldn't call you column RANK, by the way, as this is a word used by Oracle.) A sequence would be so much faster than having to query the max value 500 times a minute. And if would be so much safer with concurrent inserts.

Comment: You are right , but our customer care about the sequence of rank and he want it without gaps :)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in my comment, I see no reason for values being higher than expected. So I cannot actually answer your original question.

However, I suggest you use a sequence instead, as also mentioned in my comments above. A sequence is guaranteed to work with concurrent access, which your approach is not. To have at last consecutive values, you would use an aggregate function for that:

```
select name, row_number() over (partition by name order by seq_no) as rank_no
from tablename;
```

You can create a view, hiding seq_no and only showing rank_no. Thus your client gets what they want to see.

Comment: I think you're almost there... there's no reason for a separate sequence though; you can just use the ID column, which looks as though it's populated by a sequence. You can then drop the `RANK` column entirely.

Comment: Thanks Ben , but I can't use the ID column instead of Rank because in some cases users need to re-rank the rows and then the rank column will be updated for the group.

Comment: select name, row_number() over (partition by name order by id) as rank_no
from ##abc; I think it is little bit correct with little correction

Comment: Since you need to reorder "sometimes", leave the RANK column as null on INSERT. Have a COALESCE(RANK,ID) in your ORDER BY when you SELECT.